# Taking query result value in a script variable

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I am trying to get result of MySQL query in a variable through a script.

**My code :**

```
connect_string="mysql -vvv -username -pass -host databasename"
count=$($connect_string -e "select count(*) from tabeleName;")
echo $count
```

But am I missing something in synatx ?

Please help to find a correct way to correct it.

Comment: What about this isn't working the way you want?  Also, you'll need to specify the name of the database to use

Comment: @EricRenouf It is not showing count of table rows

Comment: @EricRenouf I mentioned sorry I ll update

Comment: Is it giving an error of any sort?

Comment: @EricRenouf No error . But it just prints select count(*) from tabeleName;

Comment: If you run the mysql command you construct by hand, I trust that works?  When run in this script `count` ends up with the select string though? Are there any special chars in the username/password/database that would cause problems, like having a `;` in one of them or something?

Comment: Please escape all the special characters between `"` including `(`, `)` and `*`